# '__builtins__' from a module different than main?

Tags: python

I've noticed the globals() dictionary contains different data inside a module vs the main script. I see the main difference is the `'__builtins__'` variable.

This is unexpected, can someone please explain why this happens?

```
$> cat main.py
import foo
print "From main", globals()

$> cat foo.py
print "From module:", globals()

$> python main.py
From module: {'__builtins__': {'bytearray': <type 'bytearray'>, 
'IndexError': <type 'exceptions.IndexError'>, 'all': <built-in function all>, 
'help': Type help() for interactive help, or help(object) for help about object.
#...much more stuff
From main {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 
'__file__': 'main.py', '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', 
'foo': <module 'foo' from '.../foo.pyc'>, '__doc__': None}
```

I'm using the Python version 2.6.6

```
$> python --version
Python 2.6.6
```

Comment: Why is this unexpected?  Maybe if we know what you're expecting, we can provide a better answer ...

Comment: I was expecting the 'globals()' to be unique inside/outside a module

Answer (score 1):

The reason why they're different is described in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals).

> `globals()` Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol
>   table. This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a
>   function or method, this is the module where it is defined, not the
>   module from which it is called).